# jQuery code does not work not understanding the markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, syntax, markup

I am trying to make a simple animation using jQuery. I have tried adding the script externally (external file) and internally(within script tags). I have tested if the page is recognizing the script using the alert function, but the script is not executing. I am thinking that is has something to do with the syntax.

```
$("#container5").hover(function() {
        //hover in
        $(#container5).animate({
            height: "250",
            width: "250",
            left: "-=50",
            top: "-=50",
            }, "fast");
            }, function() {
            //hover out
            $(#container5).animate({
            height: "200",
            width: "200",
            left: "+=50",
            top: "+=50",
            }, "fast");
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Both your internal functions need to use `$("#container5")` (with the quotes)....

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a ready function. The problem is your jQuery is running beofre the DOM is ready. This will work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#container5').animate({
       height: "250",
       width: "250",
       left: "-=50",
       top: "-=50"
    }, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a ready handler, plus you also need to wrap your strings with quotes.

You also seem to have a broken function set-up as Hellion has stated, you shouldn't be passing jQuery into a function at the point you are doing. Instead you need to be wrapping all your code in an annonymous function, with a `$` as a param, and pass jQuery into that. This is so as to protect against other libraries that may make use of a global `$` var.

Three things that will help you detect these problems in future.

- be specific with your indenting. This will highlight problems much more easily.
- Use a text editor with syntax/code highlighting - this will show you that your strings are wrong.
- check your error console in which ever browser you use, this would have given you some hints as to the illegal syntax layout.

The following should fix your issues:

```
;(function($){
  $(function(){
    $('#container5').hover(
      function(){
        $('#container5').animate({
          height: "250",
          width: "250",
          left: "-=50",
          top: "-=50",
        },"fast");
      },
      function() {
        $('#container5').animate({
          height: "200",
          width: "200",
          left: "+=50",
          top: "+=50",
        },"fast");
      }
    );
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides not being in ready handlers, your syntax is off a bit:

1: your #container needs to be in quotes always Ex: $('#container5') - OR you can just use $(this) on the hover animations because it is on the same container

2: You have an extra comma after top: "+=50" - take that out.  The last line of an animate or anything in {} can not have a comma at the end.

3: Put it in a ready function.

Here's the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container5").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({height: "250", width: "250", left: "-=50", top: "-=50"}, "fast");
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#container5').animate({height: "200", width: "200", left: "+=50", top: "+=50"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

PLEASE NOTICE: I used $(this) and $('#container5').  You can use these both interchangeably in this instance.  [Read up on $(this)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?42053-jQuery-%28this%29-usage) if you want to learn more dynamic events.